# How to loop through table and find a element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table like this. It's a big one and I have simplified it like this. With jQuery I want to check if the membership column contains "-". if yes I want to remove that row entirely. Is it possible to do?

I tried like  `$("td > tr, #membertable").each(function() {` but I am only getting a single element.

```
<table id="membertable">  
      <thread>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Name
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Membership
          </th>
        </tr>

      </thread>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Ajay
          </td>
          <td>
            -
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Simon
          </td>
          <td>
            Premium
          </td>
        </tr>
      <tbody>

    </table>
```

Comment: `td > tr` cannot give you any results as `td` cannot be the parent element of `tr`. That is why your jQuery selector only gives you `#membertable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a jQuery selector `'td:nth-child(2):contains(-)'` - find all [2nd child](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) `td` elements which [contain](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) `-` as their text. Then you can remove the parent of the `td` elements.

**Example:**

```js
$('td:nth-child(2):contains(-)').parent().remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="membertable">
  <thread>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Name
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Membership
      </th>
    </tr>

  </thread>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Ajay
      </td>
      <td>
        -
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Simon
      </td>
      <td>
        Premium
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>

</table>
```

To reverse the select (not contains) you can wrap `:contains` with the `:not` selector - `td:nth-child(2):not(:contains(-))`.

```js
$('td:nth-child(2):not(:contains(-))').parent().remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="membertable">
  <thread>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Name
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Membership
      </th>
    </tr>

  </thread>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Ajay
      </td>
      <td>
        -
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Simon
      </td>
      <td>
        Premium
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: How can I reverse? not contains?